Using static variables from other classes in dynamic queries
I am trying to run a dynamic query, using Database.query(), which includes a static variable from another class. This works correctly:
static Id x = LocalUserInfo.currUserId;
system.debug (x);
User u = Database.query ('select Id,Name from User where Id = :x');

But the following code gives the error 'System.query.Exception.  Variable does not exist: LocalUserInfo.currUserId'.
User u = Database.query ('select Id,Name from User where Id = :LocalUserInfo.currUserId');

So it looks like I am unable to use a static variable from another class directly.  Why is there a difference?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

As per the doco, you need to use the queryWithBinds method on your query.
e.g.
String query = 'select Id,Name from User where Id = :currUserId';

Map<String, Object> binds = new Map<String, Object>{'currUserId' => LocalUserInfo.currUserId };

User u = Database.queryWithBinds(query , binds , AccessLevel.USER_MODE);

